# iCloud Core Data Sync - Sync Files in Document Directory too

Tags: core-data, directory, document, icloud

I have a similar Problem like here: [iCloud with Core Data and File sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247139/icloud-with-core-data-and-file-sync/28061641?noredirect=1#comment44505014_28061641)

In my App the user can store notes with several stuff like title, text, images and some more per note. My App is Core Data based but for images I store only the URL of the images in Core Data which are saved in the documents directory.

Everything is fine but now I want to add iCloud Sync. I wanted this from day one, but iCloud is/was so buggy that I could just not get this to work. Now I found that great framework „Ensembles“ by Drew McCormack. I just started to implement it, but from what I can tell it is just great, doing exactly what I wanted and seems to be really solid.

So everything syncs fine except the images because they are not saved in Core Data directly. I read this thread here and did google a lot, but it seems to me that the best solution is to just store everything in Core Data, this way everything is syncing fine. If I had the chance I would just do this, but my App is already live with using the other solution and saving only the URL of the images in Core Data and saving the actual image in Documents Directory.

Someone said that you could use the syncing side by side using NSFileManager or „iCloud Access“. But isn´t this just a bad solution? I mean I could upload an image to iCloud when the user saves it, but I don´t know how to proper handle all that other stuff. When launching the App, check for new Images - but how? check for which? I just need the new ones, and all the merging and so on seems to be very complicated!?

So saving the images directly to Core Data would make everything much easier right? Or is there another way to sync and merge all the images in the document directory the way that is working like the sync works with Core Data with „Ensembles“ ?

My guess is it would be better and much easier and less buggy to just save everything in Core Data and let „Ensembles“ do the syncing.. !?

But as I already released my App with people having images in Document Directory, is there a way I could merge all the images from the documents directory to Core Data once? Like prompting the user in the Update to do such a merge once when he enables iCloud ?

Tanks for help !

And thanks to Drew McCormack ! Ensembles is just great, my sunshine in the dark of frustrating days and nights and weeks and month trying to get iCloud Sync to work properly ;)

Comment: It's actually Drew McCormack who built Ensembles.

Comment: Oops, of course, I just copy pasted the wrong name from another thread hrhr...